# NODE_CONFIG: unbound variable error trying to run inputoutput/cardano-node:1.35.3-new docker container [SOLVED]

Tags: cardano-node, docker

I have been trying to set up a docker container running the latest release of Cardano Node to be able to spin up a stake pool operation on Pre-Prod testnet.

I tried using the following command to set this up:

```
sudo docker run --user 0 -e NETWORK=preprod -v cardano-bpnode-ipc:/ipc -v cardano-bpnode-data:/data -e DATA_DIR=/data -e CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=/ipc/node.socket inputoutput/cardano-node:1.35.3-new
```

NB: I had to force the use of user 0 as a previous issue was that docker was unable to get permissions to create the files within the container on the volumes created for it.

When I tried to run this command to start running my Node I got the following error:

/nix/store/srm7rn76x2db1a6xg0bihz6vngz5a7km-entrypoint/bin/entrypoint: line 228: NODE_CONFIG: unbound variable

I have been attempting to ask on the IOHK Discord for advice on how to handle this error, and have been explicitly referred to Cardano Stackexchange to seek assistance.

So, I am posting the request for assistance here, as I cannot find any mention of this error anywhere else online.

I am hoping someone will be able to point me in the right direction to be able to actually spin up my container.

In fact, I wish to spin up 3. To learn SPO configuration and registration procedures.

Thank you kindly in advance for any support with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION - Requires replacing NETWORK with ENVIRONMENT on the list of options.